# Random.Range picking two numbers, if the same, pick one new

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am picking and laying sprites on top of eachother, and I am doing this by picking them at random from an array.
To give the illusion of them not reapeating, it is critical that they are not the same.

How do I achieve this, withouth adding to my array, and therefor putting my index out of the array bounds?`

```
  //Random Sprite Value
    int bloodSprite  = Random.Range(0, 12);
    int bloodSprite2 = Random.Range(0, 12);

    if (bloodSprite == bloodSprite2)
    {
        // what do I write here? (if here)
    }
```

Comment: `while (bloodSprite == bloodSprite2) { bloodSprite2 = Random.Range(0, 12); }` may work for you. You may end up choosing more than once but it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Great, thanks! When you say, "You may end up choosing more than once", do you mean that, the script will run again, to try to get a new number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do.. while` will be helpful over here

```
//Initialize default value to bloodSprite and bloodSprite2
int bloodSprite = int.MinValue;
int bloodSprite2 = int.MinValue;
do
{
    //Random Sprite Value
    bloodSprite  = Random.Range(0, 12);
    bloodSprite2 = Random.Range(0, 12);
    //At the end, check condition in while.
}while(bloodSprite == bloodSprite2);
```

---

[`int.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.minvalue?view=netcore-3.1) : It is constant represents smallest possible value of an integer.

In above solution, We defined smallest possible value of int to bloodSprit, which will update it in side `do..while()` loop

*Why we used [`do..while()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loop?*

- do..while loop execute code first and check condition at the end of loop. This allows us to execute code inside `do..while` loop at least once.

Flow chart diagram:

[image]

Comment: Cheers!

im very new, could you clarify what the int.MinValue, is/does?

appreciate the help.

Comment: Hey @JonasBrocklehurst, I updated my answer. Hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you, so very much! great answer!

I do however have a follow up question, if I may.

Why assign my bloodsprite int, to int.MinValue?
why not just wait until requesting my int, and assigning it with Random.Range?

And last thing, sry, is my understanding of int.MinValue the lowest int number that C# can understand?

Comment: @JonasBrocklehurst, is my understanding of int.MinValue the lowest int number that C# can understand?
Answer --> **yeah this is correct.**

Comment: @JonasBrocklehurst Why assign my bloodsprite int, to int.MinValue? why not just wait until requesting my int, and assigning it with Random.Range? **Answer**--> Because of **scope**. If you initialize your ints inside `do..while` loop. Scope of these variable will be only inside of curly brackets. It will be inaccessible to the condition present in `while`. That is why we need to create `bloodSprite` variables outside of `do..while` loop

Comment: @JonasBrocklehurst It would be great if you try out using do while loop with initialization of `int`(s) inside `do..while` loop. Let me know what error you get

Comment: Thanks!!

I tried removing the int.MinValue.. And i get no error messages, but I am not sure that this is what you are looking for:


        int bloodSprite;
        int bloodSprite2;
        do
        {
            //Random Sprite Value
            bloodSprite = Random.Range(0, 12);
            bloodSprite2 = Random.Range(0, 12);
            //At the end, check condition in while.
        } while (bloodSprite == bloodSprite2); 

Its more the, int.MinValue, that I am curious about?

Answer (score 1):

First get a random from 0 to 12 say x, then get a random from 0 to x - 1 or from x + 1 to 12. U can chose any.

```
int s1 = Random.Range(0, 12);
int s2 = s1 == 0 ? Random.Range(s1, 12) : Random.Range(0, s1);
```

You don't really need a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you.

```
while(bloodSprite == bloodSprite2)
{
   bloodSprite2 = Random.Range(0, 12);
}
```

Warning: there is a very very low probability of ending up in infinite while loop.